# Populate Laravel 5.2 Select box with ID and Name wihout using Form:select() facade

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-5

I know there is already a question on stackoverflow about populating select box , but there are answers given using form:select() facade

I want to populate select box but not using form facade.
I did this and it worked for me

In controller

```
public function create()
{
    $states=General_states::all('state_name','state_id');
    return view('admin.addcity',compact('states'));
}
```

In view

```
 <select class="form-control" name="movie_language">
        @foreach($states as $data)
        <option value="{{ $data->state_id }}">{{ $data->state_name }} </option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

But I want to use ::lists here like this

In Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $states=General_states::lists('state_name','state_id');
    return view('admin.addcity',compact('states'));
}
```

But In view I am getting error message as trying to get the property of Non Object.
Help me so that I can use lists in controller and populate select box in view without using {{form::select() }}

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need filtering here is a short hand way.suppose your `General_states` namespace is `App\`

```
{!! Form::select('movie_language', App\General_states::lists('state_name','state_id'),'', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

or if you want to another way just send me the dump of after changing your code like this and executing.

```
public function create()
{
    $states=General_states::lists('state_name','state_id');
    dd($states);
    return view('admin.addcity',compact('states'));
}
```